# Issue regarding ruby mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, submit, mechanize

I want to login into a web portal.There is a form .But the main problem is that there are two submit buttons in the form. One with  value "Normal Login" and another with value "Special Login for utilisation".Now I want to submit the form using the button with "Normal Login" value.

My ruby code is:-

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://egov.wbcomtax.gov.in/DematWaybill/index.jsp')
pp page                     #The page view for first time

login_section= page.forms.first
user_id_value= login_section.field_with(name: "txtUserID")
user_id_value.value="******" 
password_value=login_section.field_with(name: "txtPassword")
password_value.value="*********"

pp user_id_value
pp password_value

home_page=login_section.submit(login_section.button_with(:value=>'Normal Login'))

pp home_page                 #printing the same page
```

Now when I use the line home_page=login_section.submit(login_section.button_with(:value=>'Normal Login')) it is throwing error.

Please tell me how to do it.

The form is:

```
<form name="frmLogin" method="post">
 <input type="text" class="textboxc" id="txtUserID3" name="txtUserID"> 
 <input class="textboxc" id="txtPassword" type="password" name="txtPassword" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Normal Login" onclick="return check_user()">
<input type="Submit" value="Special Login for utilisation" onclick="return check_user2()">
</form>
```

Please help me.Thank you in advance.

It is showing the page data once again. I have mentioned pp page in my code and then metioned pp home_page. Both are printing same

Here is my terminal view:

```
C:\Ruby22\code>ruby actual_machine_test.rb
#<Mechanize::Page
{url #<URI::HTTP http://egov.wbcomtax.gov.in/DematWaybill/index.jsp>}
{meta_refresh}
{title "DEMATERIALIZED WAYBILL- Login."}
{iframes}
{frames}
{links
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "idforpassword.jsp">
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "http://www.wb.nic.in/">
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "http://wbcomtax.gov.in/link.htm">
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "http://wbcomtax.gov.in/disclaimer.htm">}
{forms
 #<Mechanize::Form
 {name "frmLogin"}
 {method "POST"}
 {action "http://egov.wbcomtax.gov.in/DematWaybill/index.jsp"}
 {fields
  [text:0x1f10260 type: text name: txtUserID value: ]
  [field:0x2867f84 type: password name: txtPassword value: ]}
  {radiobuttons}
  {checkboxes}
  {file_uploads}
  {buttons
  [submit:0x2867e58 type: submit name: Submit value: Normal Login]
  [submit:0x2867cc8 type: Submit name:  value: Special Login for  utilisation]}>}>
  [text:0x1f10260 type: text name: txtUserID value: MARK5705]
  [field:0x2867f84 type: password name: txtPassword value: mark*008]


  #<Mechanize::Page
  {url #<URI::HTTP http://egov.wbcomtax.gov.in/DematWaybill/index.jsp>}
  {meta_refresh}
  {title "DEMATERIALIZED WAYBILL- Login."}
  {iframes}
  {frames}
  {links
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "idforpassword.jsp">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "http://www.wb.nic.in/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "http://wbcomtax.gov.in/link.htm">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "http://wbcomtax.gov.in/disclaimer.htm">}
  {forms
  #<Mechanize::Form
  {name "frmLogin"}
  {method "POST"}
  {action "http://egov.wbcomtax.gov.in/DematWaybill/index.jsp"}
  {fields
  [text:0x28ea54c type: text name: txtUserID value: ]
  [field:0x28ea3f8 type: password name: txtPassword value: ]}
   {radiobuttons}
   {checkboxes}
   {file_uploads}
   {buttons
   [submit:0x28ea2cc type: submit name: Submit value: Normal Login]
   [submit:0x28ea13c type: Submit name:  value: Special Login for utilisation]}>}>
   ................................
```

Comment: Please show us the error you are getting and ensure the form you excerpted includes all the fields (I do not see username/password field).

Comment: @Felix...I have updates accordingly.

Comment: The submit buttons have javascript functions attached with them by onclick event. Does this create the problem? Does mechanize support javascript?

Comment: Mechanize does not support javascript

Comment: so ,,what should I do? Please help me to get proper solution.